# How to share contents between widgets in gjs

Tags: javascript, gtk3, gjs

I'm trying to create a simple web editor demo. I want a web view widget to render the contents of a gtk source view widget...
I have the widgets drawn, but I can't get the content out of the sourceview to give it to the webview.
I thought I should use a buffer, but I can't get them to share a buffer.
How is that supposed to work?
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

something like this is what I was thinking:

```
const htmlBuffer = new GtkSource.Buffer();
const messagehtml = new GtkSource.View(htmlBuffer);
const webView = new Webkit.WebView({ vexpand: true });

htmlBuffer.connect('changed', upDateWebView);
```

Then in the upDateWebView() method, call

```
webView.load_html(htmlBuffer);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It looks like `GtkSource.Buffer` is a subclass of `Gtk.TextBuffer`, so it should have a `text` property you can pass to `WebView.load_html()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... I finally got it to work like this:

```
const htmlBuffer = new GtkSource.Buffer();
const messagehtml = new GtkSource.View({ buffer: htmlBuffer });
const webView = new Webkit.WebView({ vexpand: true });


  htmlBuffer.connect('changed', function () {
    webView.load_html(htmlBuffer.text, null);
  });
```